# Телеграм бот имеет огромную задержку при взаимодействии с телефона

Tags: telegram

написал с помощью chatgpt бота с игрой. (Понятное дело, что он кривой, но хоть так начал учить питон, да и бот больше для себя). Бот - это игра в формате quiz для групповых чатов. Бот молниеносно работает при взаимодействии с приложения телеграма для виндоус. Но как только начинаешь взаимодействовать с телефона бывает задержка в несколько секунд. Пример: пользователь с телефона отправляет правильный ответ, бот сразу отвечает (это видно если сидеть в той же группе с приложения на виндовс) но для пользователю на телефон эта реакция может прийти где то через 2.5 секунды. Как я себе понимаю значит проблема не в коде и не в сервере... но куда копать даже представить не могу.

Comment: Может дело в скорости подключения мобильного устройства?

Comment: Компьютер и телефон на одном вай фае. Тестировал на разных телефонах, в разных wi fi сетях, на разных компьютерах.